# How to place Drawer widget on the right

Tags: flutter

How to place Drawer widget on the right. Also is possible to place two Drawer widget in a single page one either side of the appbar

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
 return Scaffold(
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
          title: Text('Checkout'),
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.report),
          title: Text('Transactions'),
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/transactionsList');
          },
        ),
      ]
    )
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children : [
        _buildOrderHeader(),
        _buildOrderDetails(context),
      ]
    )
  )
);
```

}'

Comment: use `endDrawer`  in the scaffold

Comment: Thanks for the support. It worked . 
Is it possible to change the drawer icon?

Comment: using the `leading` property in the `appBar `

Comment: I need to change the icon of the endDrawer. Also Im unable to open endDrawer

Answer (score 175, accepted):

By using `endDrawer: ...` instead or in addition to `drawer: ...` to set a drawer, like this:

```dart
Scaffold(
  endDrawer: Drawer(...),
  // ...
)
```

To open it programmatically, use

```
Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer(); //This might have been updated by flutter team since the last edit
```

See also https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/endDrawer.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I need to open the endDrawer when the appbar Action button is taped

Comment: `Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer()` https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/openEndDrawer.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Finally, able to get past my hero, [ranking #2](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flutter/topusers) in Flutter.

Comment: `drawer` widget in flutter, default opens from left-to-right and the `endDrawer` by default opens from right-to-left.

Answer (score 10):

To open navigation drawer from right side with Dart Null Safety, You should use endDrawer(). There is two drawer arguments available in flutter.

1. Drawer (left side)
2. endDrawer (Right side)
   you can see the example for endDrawer.

To open endDrawer on Button click.

```dart
_scaffoldKey.currentState!.openEndDrawer();
```

Create Global Key

```dart
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

inside Build()

```dart
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: backgroundcolor_cust,
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  endDrawer: Drawer(
    elevation: 16.0,
    child: leftDrawerMenu(context, user_phone, cart_count),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 8):

```dart
endDrawer: Drawer(
  child: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: const [
        Text('End Drawer'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Builder(
              builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                key: _scaffoldKey,
                endDrawer: Drawer(
                  child: ListView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      DrawerHeader(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 40,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.account_circle_outlined,
                                size: 60,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Text(
                              'User Name',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Item 1'),
                        onTap: () {
                          // Handle item 1 tap
                        },
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text('Item 2'),
                        onTap: () {
                          // Handle item 2 tap
                        },
                      ),
                      // ... (add more ListTile widgets for other items)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep the button on right and the drawer in the left, then add the hamburger button inside a container, so that hamburger button will be on the right side and the navigation drawer remains in the left side. (not recommended)

```
new Container(
  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, right: 10.0),
  child: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.menu,
      size: 24,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    onPressed: () => scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
  ),
)
```