# Is there any similar widget or function like 'showModelBottomSheet' that pop on screen from right hand side in flutter?

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet, flutter-widget, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I used `showModelBottomSheet` a lot that pops on the screen from the bottom with a nice animation.

Now I want to use something similar that pops on the screen from the right-hand side instead of the bottom.

It helps me a lot for UI purposes when the user rotates the screen to landscape, then I want to show a pop up from right in the flutter.

I tried to find and also dig deeper inside `showModelBottomSheet` function but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using drawer on right side it may solve your problem
answered in link below
[How to place Drawer widget on the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300696/how-to-place-drawer-widget-on-the-right)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that exists either in Material or Cupertino design language, so no, unfortunately. However, you could build that yourself pretty easily with a `Stack` widget.