# Flutter- add drawer into bottomNavigationBarItem with other items and navigate

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Generally, we use drawer into appBar(position drawer/endDrawer). I've to set the drawer functionality into Bottom Navigation Bar Item with Home, Setting. These 3 items will be workable for all page and have to display selected index of these Three(3) items. How I can achieve this.

```
class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      onTap: onTabTapped,
      //for more than three items
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(processIcon),
          label: 'My Task',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Home',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(settingIcon),
            label: 'Setting',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(menuIcon),
          label: 'Menu',
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      print('index ${index}');
    });

  }
}
```

Here the Drawer will be navigated into Menu.

Comment: can you please describe this quetion in detail I have defeculty to understand it

Comment: Primarily I need to open and close drawer by click on the Menu button on the bottom navigation bar item. The next part is suppose I want to go Setting page from any page of my application and the Setting will be display as Selected as I clicked and go to Setting page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GlobalKey`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html)  on [`Scaffold`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) and use it to open drawer.

```dart
 void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;

      if (_selectedIndex == 3 && _scaffoldKey.currentState != null) {
        _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
      } });
  }
```

```dart
class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 1;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Text("B $_selectedIndex"),
      drawer: const Drawer(
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
```

Comment: How can I set drawer transition from right to left?

Comment: Wrap with `Directionality(textDirection:TextDirection.rtl,child:Drawer())`

Comment: I don't want to change textdirection. Just want to open the Drawer like the opening from right to left while we use Drawer() in endDrawer.

Comment: Basically is will change inner child directionality, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53300696/10157127)

Comment: This work. But when I'm using endDrawer the Hamburger is visible into the right side of appBar at the same time whereas I want to open it by clicking on Menu. How to remove this Hamburger icon from right side of the appBar?

Comment: you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49034480/10157127)

Comment: Glad to help you out. You can check [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/) to explore more about widgets.